# How to pass all Eloquent (ORM) results throught a Laravel dataTransformer?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, transformer-model

I getting results from a query built using Eloquent (Laravel's ORM)

```
$query = Lawyer::whereHas('user', function($q) use ($request) {
            $q->where('is_active', true);
        });
$result = $query->get()
```

I would like to pass the results I get throught a trasformer `class LawyerTransformer extends TransformerAbstract{}` to add some data to the results.

When I try this :

```
$this->collection($query->get(), new LawyerTransformer())
```

I have the following issue : `Method [collection] does not exist.`

**How can I transform all the results using a transformer ?**

Comment: Have you tried what it says in the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-transform? Btw the result of ```$query->get()``` is already a collection most likely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the transform method on the collection instance to achieve something like that here is an example that will increment all values in an array by 1;

```
$collection = collect([1, 2, 3]);

$collection->transform(function ($item, $key) {
    return (new IncrementTransformer)->transform($item);
});
```

And the transfomer class

```
class IncrementTransformer
{
    public function transform($item)
    {
        return $item += 1;
    }
}
```

You could probably write this a little cleaner but you get the basic idea.

Comment: Thanks, that's the response I was waiting for. I just didn't understand the collection object and how to use the transformer object on it. Now I got it. Thanks !